# Fastest way to list diagonal elements of a 2D array from a given point

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming

In a 2D array, for a given point what is the fastest way to get the diagonal elements in Scala? I understand that I can simply use a for loop to walk through the elements from a given point, but it feels very java-like. One of the ways I have come up with is to use a recursive function which accepts a function as an argument that calculates the next cell. However I feel such a method is very inefficient. What is the most idiomatic way in Scala to walk through a diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast functional code in Scala generally involves tail-recursive functions, and fast array access generally involves indexing.  So your options are limited.

In this case,

```
def diag(xss: Array[Array[Double]]): Array[Double] = {
  val ans = new Array[Double](xss.length)
  @annotation.tailrec def inner(i: Int) {
    if (i < xss.length) {
      ans(i) = xss(i)(i)
      inner(i+1)
    }
  }
  inner(0)
  ans
}
```

Personally, I find this less clear than the corresponding while loop

```
def diag(xss: Array[Array[Double]]): Array[Double] = {
  val ans = new Array[Double](xss.length)
  var i = 0
  while (i < xss.length) {
    ans(i) = xss(i)(i)
    i += 1
  }
  ans
}
```

but your preferences may vary.

There are optimization frameworks that will take higher-order index traversal (e.g. `for (i <- xss.indices) ans(i) = xss(i)(i)`) and change it into the while loop.  (ScalaBlitz is one.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Tail recursion` and Immutable data-structures like `List` as functional programming and immutability just go along very well. it offers two operations head and tail which takes constant time and Time-complexity of both operation is O(1).

```
 @annotation.tailrec
  def f(arr: List[List[Int]], res: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = {
    if (arr.isEmpty) res
    else 
      f(arr.tail.map(_.tail), res :+ arr.head.head)
  }

  val x = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8), List(9, 10, 11, 12), List(13, 14, 15, 16))

scala> f(x)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 6, 11, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, some (arguably) more colloquial Scala, noticing that diagonal elements are issued from a rotation of lines, you may use code as follows. It'll be less efficient than a for loop though.

```
def diag(m: Array[Array[Int]]) = {
  val (m1, m2) = m.zipWithIndex.
    map{case (l, i) => val (l1, l2) = splitAt(l.size-i); l1 ++ l2}.
    transpose.zipWithIndex.
    map{case (l, i) => l.splitAt(i+1)}.
    unzip
  m1 ++ m2.init
}
```